# Continuous integration involving several teams working on the same application

Tags: svn, jenkins, merge, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am working on a project which involves several teams developing the same application using SVN. each team develops their part of the application independently in a separate branch, then tests and deploys the application. after a successful deployment, the team will compare the code in their branch with the code in the trunk and update the trunk with their changes so that the other teams can also get their changes. Also, prior to deploying the application, the team also compares the code in the trunk to with the code in their branch and update their branch with the latest changes from the trunk so that the code which they will deploy will contain the latest changes from the other teams.
Now we would like to automate this process with Jenkins but we are finding it difficult to define a standard process. for instance, we thought of the following approach:

- a developer of a team creates a new branch in SVN which contains the code from the trunk
- he updates the code with his changes and performs unit testing
- if the unit testing is successful he checks in the code in the branch, creates a tag and triggers the deployment process
- the package is deployed to some tests environments on which testing is performed(smoke, functional, etc) and is eventually deployed to production if the tests are successful

the problem with this approach is that this team does not include the changes which were made by other teams while it was doing the deployment to the various test environments. so a workaround could be to merge the latest updates from the trunk into our branch during the deployment process but this will mean that the new merged code will not be tested through all the test environments.

we thought of using [Multi-stage continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-stage_continuous_integration) but it would not work because the teams do not do their deployments at the same time or period.

So anyone has an idea on the approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

What you do is not actually continuous integration - each team works on a different branch. Hence your problems :)

In continuous integration all developers would work on the **same** (integration) branch so the issues you mention do not exist, everyone is on the same page. The CI system would be applied to the integration branch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although the various teams work on different branches, they all merge their code to the trunk. This is similar to multi-stage continous integration

Comment: Well, you either switch to a single branch or you perform all testing in all branches...